# ios cannot add new marker after passing data back to parent ViewController with EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, google-maps, delegates, exc-bad-access

I am trying to implement the module for setting the map parameters before adding the new marker.

The flow is initialing new SliderViewCOntroller from parent mapViewController. After setting the values at SliderViewController and saving their values, it passes back to the parent mapViewCOntroller with new coordinates added. For the time being, the variable for the coordinates are only the global variables on the mapViewCOntroller

Actually, after saving the parameters, it shows the EXEC_BAD)ACCESS (code=1 , address = 0xc)
The code highlights at the

```
[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

on the SliderViewController.m

Would you please tell me are there any other alternatives to pass the data back from child viewController to parent ViewController using protocols and delegate ?

The below is my working:

MapViewController.h

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SliderViewController.h"


@interface MapViewController : UIViewController<GMSMapViewDelegate , SliderViewControllerDelegate>{


}

@property (nonatomic) float verticalSliderValue;
@property (nonatomic) float circleSliderValue;


@end
```

MapViewController.m

```
//initiaing
-(void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didLongPressAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{

    p = coordinate;
    SliderViewController * sliderVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SliderViewController"];
    sliderVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0];
    sliderVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentViewController:sliderVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
    [sliderVC release];

}

//receiving 
    - (void)passValue:(float )value1 : (float )valueCiruclar
    {
        NSLog(@"This was returned from ViewControllerB %ff",value1);
        NSLog(@"This was returned from ViewControllerSlider %ff",valueCiruclar);

        CheckPoints *myCar=[[CheckPoints alloc] init];
        [myCar setState:0];
        [myCar setLatitude:p.latitude];
        [myCar setLongitude:p.longitude];
        NSString* theTextValue = @"Desitnation";
        [myCar setDesp:theTextValue];

        [array addObject:myCar];
        CheckPoints *lastChk = array.lastObject;
        [self writeToTextFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@", lastChk.getDesp , @"\n",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", lastChk.getLatitude],
                               @"\n", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", lastChk.getLongitude], @"\n" ]];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setFloat:lastChk.getLatitude forKey:@"lati"];
        [defaults setFloat:lastChk.getLongitude forKey:@"longi"];
        [defaults setObject:lastChk.getDesp forKey:@"desp"];
        [defaults synchronize];

        for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
            CheckPoints *current =  [array objectAtIndex:i];
            if(current.getLatitude != lastChk.getLatitude && current.getLongitude != lastChk.getLongitude){
                [current setState:1];
                NSString* previousTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"Checkpoint" ,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i+1]];
                [current setDesp:previousTitle];
            }
        }
        [self addMarkers];



    }
```

SliderViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "EFCircularSlider.h"



@protocol SliderViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)passData:(float )itemVertical : (float )itemCircular  ;
@end


@interface SliderViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *uiValue;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *uiSlider;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnReset;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *uiValue2;
@property (strong, nonatomic)  EFCircularSlider* circularSlider;
@property (nonatomic) float verticalSliderValue;
@property (nonatomic) float circleSliderValue;
@property (nonatomic) id <SliderViewControllerDelegate> delegate;


- (IBAction)reset:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)sliderChange:(id)sender;
- (void)buttonClicked: (id)sender;


@end
```

SliderViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)reset:(id)sender {
    [self writeToTextFile:valueV :valueC];
    self.uiValue.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f" , 0.00];
    [self.uiSlider setValue:0.00];
    self.uiValue2.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f" , 0.00];
    [_circularSlider setCurrentValue:0.0f];


MapViewController * sliderVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapViewController"];
[self.delegate passData:_uiSlider.value :_circularSlider.currentValue  ];
sliderVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

  }
```